# Fibonacci sequence in C

Tags: c, beginner, fibonacci-sequence

I'm very new to C, so pointing out better ways of doing things, errors, bad practices, etc would be optimal at this stage.

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/brandonwamboldt/projects/blob/master/fibonacci/fib.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *calculateFibonacciSequence(int n, int start)
{
  int i;

  // Allocate memory for our fibonacci sequence from the heap
  int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

  // Need to calculate at least one number
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Can't start with a number under zero
  if (start != 0 && start != 1) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Get the seed values
  if (start == 0) {
      numbers[0] = 0;
      numbers[1] = 1;
  } else {
      numbers[0] = 1;
      numbers[1] = 1;
  }

  // Calculate the sequence
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i] + numbers[i - 1];
  }

  return numbers;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, n;
  int start = 0;
  int *sequence;

  // Check to see how many arguments we got
  if (argc <= 1) {
    puts("Please pass the number of iterations to run.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Get the number of iterations to run
  n = atoi(argv[1]);

  // Did they specify a start value
  if (argc > 2) {
    start = atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  // Calculate the sequence
  sequence = calculateFibonacciSequence(n, start);

  // Output the sequence
  if (sequence) {
    printf("%d", sequence[0]);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      printf(",%d", sequence[i]);
    }

    // Newline
    puts("");
  } else {
    puts("Error processing fibonacci sequence");
  }

  // Free memory
  free(sequence);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you're just printing the numbers, what is your original task: to print them or to compute them in an array?

Comment: @syb0rg I accepted your answer just now. Originally I was giving people time to post/edit and then I forgot to accept an answer. While your recursive example doesn't really do what I want, your post is very informative. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt Thanks! I did add a faster iterative solution in case you did not want recursion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### What you did well on:

- Your program is easy to read.
- You are allocating memory, even though it is unsafe in certain cases (other answers have addressed this, so I won't cover it).
- You prepare for some corner cases.

---

### Things you could improve:

- You are returning `0` when your program runs into a problem (except
  in one spot where there are too many parameters being entered).

  ```
  return 0;
  ```

  `0` is typically the return code for a exiting successfully.  If we
  run into a problem in our program, we should return something to
  indicate we ran into a problem.  I prefer to return negative numbers.

  ```
  return -1;
  ```

  Also, you should return different numbers for different errors.  A user generated error such as malformed input should not return the same error code as an internal error.  This makes debugging a lot easier when you are trying to determine the cause of an error.

  However, since you are returning an `int*`, it would be better to return `NULL` instead.  This is what you are doing right now, in a somewhat abnormal way by returning 0.  Just return `NULL`.

  ```
  return NULL;
  ```
- You should mark `int`s as `unsigned` if they are never going to be negative.

  ```
  unsigned int start;
  ```
- You are not maximizing how many Fibonacci you can produce using only an `int`, or even an `unsigned int`.  An `unsigned int` has a maximum value of 2147483647, where a `long long unsigned int` has a maximum value of 18446744073709551615.  That's 8589934562 times larger!
- Declare `i` inside of your `for` loops.  This is part of the [C99 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), so you may have to adjust how you compile your program.

  ```
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  ```
- I don't see the point of the `start` variable.  Unless this is part of some problem you are trying to solve, I would just print the whole sequence.  It would cut down on your lines of code a lot as well.
- The Fibonacci series is a great place to practice recursion.

  ```
  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
     if (n < 2) return n;
     else return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
  }
  ```

  This algorithm here is short, and gets the job done just has you did in less lines of code.  We could even shorten it a bit further if we wanted to (with ternary operators).

  ```
  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      return (n < 2)? n : fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
  }
  ```

  We have to be careful though to [avoid repeating the calculation of results for previously processed inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm); to do this we should use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). I've implemented this in my final program.
- Keep in mind that sometimes recursion will make your algorithm a bit
  slower with time-complexity, which can be the case here (depending on your implementation of an iterative solution).  Here is the fastest iterative algorithm I could work up (this may still be a bit slower with the `pow()` function).

  ```
  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      return (1/sqrt(5)) * (pow(((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2), n) - pow(((1 - sqrt(5)) / 2), n));
  }
  ```

  However, using this method requires the use of `double`s, and the `return` will make an implicit cast that could cause some rounding problems.  Therefore, we will `round()` the result in our final code.
- You should test if you input is a number, and not some malformed input.

  ```
  if (scanf("%i", &num) <= 0)
  {
      puts("Invalid input.");
      return -1;
  }
  ```

---

### Final code:

- #### Iterative: O(1)

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>

  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      return round((1/sqrt(5)) * (pow(((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2), n) - pow(((1 - sqrt(5)) / 2), n)));
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      unsigned int num = 0;

      printf("Enter how far to calculate the series: ");
      if (scanf("%i", &num) <= 0)
      {
          puts("Invalid input.");
          return -1;
      }

      for(unsigned int n = 1; n < num + 1; ++n) printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(n));
  }
  ```
- #### Recursion: O(n)

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define ARRAYLENGTH 100 // keep in mind the result must fit in an llu int (fibonacci values grow rapidly)
                          // you will run into issues after 93, so set the length at 100
  long long int memoization[ARRAYLENGTH];

  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      if (memoization[n] != -1) return memoization[n];

      return (n < 2)? n : (memoization[n] = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      unsigned int num = 0;

      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++) memoization[i] = -1; // preset array

      printf("Enter how far to calculate the series: ");
      if (scanf("%i", &num) <= 0)
      {
          puts("Invalid input.");
          return -1;
      }
      if (num < ARRAYLENGTH)
      {
          for(unsigned int n = 1; n < num + 1; ++n) printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(n));
      }
      else
      {
          puts("Input number is larger than the array length.");
          return -2;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Isn't declaring the loop counter inside the loop statement a syntax error in C?  Or does the OP have C99?

Comment: @Jamal It was an error, so I kept that part how it was

Comment: @Jamal Yes, in older standards. But C99 is the "lowest" standard that should be used (in my opinion).

Comment: Okay.  For the short time I've written C (mostly in just one class), I was always used to declaring it outside since C99 wasn't in use.

Comment: I think you got confused by the trap that I pointed out in my answer: that's a `NULL` pointer being returned, not a number 0. Returning `-1` as a pointer to indicate an error condition would be really weird.

Comment: According to @Loki, current thinking in the C/C++ world is that `unsigned` types are more trouble than they are worth, especially when you won't be going anywhere near the maximum value (like `start`).

Comment: I'd consider the global array, with a fixed size limit, and recursion not an improvement, but rather three steps back.

Comment: @syb0rg: You "final code" is broken: In `main()` you have a `char temp` and `scanf("%s", &temp)`. That's asking for a buffer overflow. Also, it can calculate at most the ninth Fibonacci number due to the single digit.

Comment: @EOF I would be interested to talk to you more about that in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: @200_success I said Fibonacci was a great place to practice recursion, it may not be the most efficient. I have now included an iterative example as well.

Comment: The double precision formula should be rounded, or you may get wrong results (x.99999999 -> x when it should be x+1).

Comment: @VedranŠego You should visit me in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) so we can talk more about this.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't here. My reasoning is simple: the result of the above expression is, in theory, an integer. Due to rounding errors, it is possible that the obtained result is non-integer. Conversion to `int` is a truncation, so if the computed result is smaller than the exact one (even by as little as the machine precision), this will get truncated and will give the wrong result. I don't have the example when it actually happens. Maybe never, but it depends on various factors which you cannot test all (i.e., all possible processors), so I go with the "better safe than sorry" approach.

Answer (score 12):

You C is very good.  Just a few comments:

The `start` parameter is pointless.  Just print the whole sequence.

Don't allocate memory until you know your parameters are valid.  Else you have
a memory leak.

You don't check that the `numbers[]` array was allocated successfully and you
have overflowed the array by one place.

Define loop variables in the loop where possible:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {...}
```

Many of your comments are not useful.  They might be required by your
supervisor (if you have one) but in normal code would be considered 'noise'.  Comments should add something that the reader can't see for himself.  Usually 'why' is a better question to answer than 'what', as for good code, what you are doing should be self-evident.

Defining variables where they are needed, not at the beginning of functions, is
often considered best practice.

EDIT: Also, to add a new line, `putchar('\n');` would be more normal.

Comment: Hmm, I may have re-iterated some points you had.  My answer was in the works when you posted this and didn't notice.

Comment: No problem - if we both thought the same things, there's perhaps more chance of them being true :-)  BTW your recursive solution is notationally neat but horribly inefficient.  Do a Fibonacci of 46 and it calls `fibonacci` 9615053904 times (and takes correspondingly long).

Comment: Yeah, I think I had a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).  I have edited in a solution that uses [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) now, which is much faster.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is rather unsafe.

You allocate memory using `malloc()`, based on a user-submitted number that is never checked. If the user supplies **-1** in `argv[1]`, `malloc()` will try to allocate **0xFFFFFFFC** bytes on a 32- or  **0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC** bytes on a 64-bit two's-complement architecture. This may fail.

The return value of `malloc()` is never checked, which may lead to a segmentation-fault if `malloc()` failed and the resulting null-pointer is subsequently dereferenced.

After you allocate your buffer, you check for input validity, and if the check fails, the function returns **0**. `main()` treats this return value as a pointer and `free()`'s it, but if an error occurred in the function, **0** is passed to `free()` instead of the pointer to the allocation and the allocated memory is leaked.

In this case it doesn't matter, because the program exits and all memory is automatically freed on program exit, but for a bigger project this would not work.

The code should be rewritten.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Never had to do memory management manually before.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the world of C and its pitfalls.

In particular, you have a memory leak if the parameters to `calculateFibonacciSequence()` fail validation.  That is, you call `malloc()`, but the `numbers` pointer will be lost forever once you `return 0`.  The solution would be to postpone `malloc()` until after the parameters pass validation.

Also in `calculateFibonacciSequence()`, you wrote `return 0`, but you are actually returning a null pointer, not a number 0.  It would be clearer to write `return NULL`.

As a nitpick, I think two spaces for indentation is too stingy for readability.  Small indentation also encourages excessive nesting, which is poor programming practice.  Try four spaces instead.

Overall, though, not bad!